# Is it idiomatic to say 'go on **the** ride'?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

An [ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/147471/350749) says

> Go on a ride suggests having a thrilling experience at a theme park. Go for a ride suggests an excursion on a bicycle, a motor cycle or a horse.

So, I am aware of the concept of 'go on a ride'.

I see an example somewhere

> I am feeling very dizzy after going on **the** ride.

where the speaker used '*the*'.

I am aware the rule that '*the*' is used when sth/sb has been mentioned. In this case the activity 'go on a ride' indeed had been mentioned though, I guess 'go on a ride' is a fixed combination.

## question

Is it idiomatic to say 'go on **the** ride'?

Comment: Whether you use the definite or indefinite article makes no difference whatever to the verb you use - so, yes _go on the ride_ is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Go on a ride" uses an indefinite article because it can apply to any number of different rides.     "... dizzy after going on the ride" uses a definite article because it is exactly one ride that has made me dizzy.